# How to pass a function to another component using react router Link in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new in React js. I am using react class component and here i need to pass a function to another component using Link. I know this is an older question but i didn't given any proper solution of this question that's the reason i am posting a new question.

```
myFunction=()=>{
    console.log("calling..")
}

<Link 
   to={{
   pathname: '/category',
     state:{
        myFunction: this.myFunction
     }
}}>View Category</Link>
```

**Here is my route -**

```
<Route path="/category" render={(routeProps)=>
    <Editor myFunction={routeProps.myFunction} {...routeProps} />
}/>
```

> This is how I am calling the above passing function this.props.location.state.myFunction();

**But this is giving me below error -**

> DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { [native code] } could not be cloned.

Please help me any one.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the use case, why you can't pass `myFunction: myFunction` inside Route?

Comment: @TJ thanks for your reply. My requirement is i have defined a function "myFunction" in a component and i want to use that function from another category component. Category component i am rendering using <Link to="/category"></Link>. So i am passing "myFunction" using link state like above. But it giving me error.

Comment: Why not export this function and import it from the other comoponet?

Comment: No i don't want to use export, import for this scenario...I just want to call this function in this way this.props.location.state.myFunction() from category component.

Answer (score 0):

You should return something from the function as below instead of checking with **console.log**

`myFunction=()=>{ return {name:"xxxx"} }`

Pass `this.myFunction()` in route state.

`<Link to={{ pathname: '/category', state: { myFunction : this.myFunction() }}}>View Category</Link>`

Check the result on navigated component as `this.props.location.state.myFunction;`